# angularjs $modal.open not working in locationChangeStart

Tags: angularjs

I want to show a modal dialog box when a user clicks on the browser's back button. If he clicks on the proceed button, I would like to redirect to another location. With the `event.preventDefault()`, nothing happens, but without it, the modal opens, although the browser redirects.

```
$scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, nextUrl, current) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'confirm.html',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
        resolve: {
           items: function () {
               return $scope.session.event_id;
           }
        }
    });

    // If I remove this line, the modal is working but the browser location changes.
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: could you create a plunkr ? Would be helpful in debugging your code.

Comment: Thank you ,Finally i got the solution above one myself. i have changed above lotionchangestart to routeChangeStart then i have re locate the path